# My CPT won't display no matter what I do

Tags: custom-post-types

I create CPT and add new post. I can see that post in the Recent Posts but when follow the URL to that post, it only display the message "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND."

I try to follow the instruction on many site and still can't solve this problem. I've already create single-{post-type}.php and the loop too but nothing change.

I use the Instant Wordpress 4.5 for local host and create a child theme from TwentySevenTeen, is it somehow caused this issue?

Please help me with this case, I try anything from yesterday and feel completely lost. Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after creating CPT, go to **Settings --> Permalinks** and save them.

Comment: You saved me @bravokeyl, this is exactly what I need. Thanks very much for your help.